# JavaScript Azure Function stacktrace has none of my code in it

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a simple Azure Function where I'm throwing an exception.

it's one line consisting of `throw new Error('Oh no... we hit an edge case')`

Curiously, my stacktrace is just some .NET stacktrace

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 293)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__14.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 89)
Inner exception Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc.RpcException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerLanguageInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\Rpc\WorkerLanguageInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 74)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase+<Invoke>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionInvokerBase.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 84)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 20)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 63)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeAsync>d__25.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 556)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 503)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 439)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 249)
```

And even more peculiar, I can clearly see that my stacktrace has been captured *somewhere*.  Even if I check or uncheck 'just my code' I get nothing that would show me my error + stacktrace

So of course my question is: **how do I see my error and my code's stacktrace in appinsights?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When functions pass exception to ApplicaitonInsights, it is an outer exception with InnerException that comes from user code. I've started the discussion if this is correct here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2156

For javascript Functions it's even more interesting: inner exception's message contains language specific exception, e.g.

```
Result: Failure
Exception: Oh no... we hit an edge case
Stack:
```

ApplicationInsights SDK/logger send all this info and if you go to Analytics, you'll see in exception.details in the parsedStack[1] your exception, just run something like

```
exceptions | where tostring(details) contains "Oh no... we hit an edge case"
```

The portal, on the other side, does not show `innermostType`, `innermostMessage` or inner exceptions messages. Please send the feedback to the portal team about it!

Comment: Re: inner messages - that was a bug in UX. It is fixed and on its way to prod (ETA: 4/2).

Answer (score 0):

To log your exception in Application insights just use `context.log` like normal instead of throwing it.

```
try {
some code...
} 
catch (error) {
context.log('Error getting content' + error)
}
```

The stack-trace which you are seeing is actually from function host as it is written in .net core

Answer (score 0):

To get diagnostic data specific to your app, you can insert code to send your own telemetry data.

You have several options:

•   [TrackEvent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent) is typically used for monitoring usage patterns, but the data it sends also appears under Custom Events in diagnostic search. Events are named, and can carry string properties and numeric metrics on which you can filter your diagnostic searches.

•   [TrackTrace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#tracktrace) lets you send longer data such as POST information.

•   [TrackException()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#exceptions) sends stack traces. More about exceptions.

•   If you already use a logging framework like Log4Net or NLog, you can capture those logs and see them in diagnostic search alongside request and exception data.

To see these events, open Search, open Filter, and then choose Custom Event, Trace, or Exception.

[image]

**Capturing exceptions and related diagnostic data**

At first, you won't see in the portal all the exceptions that cause failures in your app. You'll see any browser exceptions. But most server exceptions are caught by IIS and you have to write a bit of code to see them.
You can:

•   Log exceptions explicitly by inserting code in exception handlers to report the exceptions.

•   Capture exceptions automatically by configuring your ASP.NET framework. The necessary additions are different for different types of framework.
Simplest way to track exception in your code

```
try
    { ...
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
      appInsights.trackException(ex, "handler loc",
        {Game: currentGame.Name,
         State: currentGame.State.ToString()});
    }


var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
    ...
    try
    { ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Set up some properties:
       var properties = new Dictionary <string, string>
         {{"Game", currentGame.Name}};

       var measurements = new Dictionary <string, double>
         {{"Users", currentGame.Users.Count}};

       // Send the exception telemetry:
       telemetry.TrackException(ex, properties, measurements);
    }
```

in Java Script

```
const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup();
const client = appInsights.defaultClient;

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    client.trackEvent({name: "my custom event", tagOverrides:{"ai.operation.id": context.invocationId}, properties: {customProperty2: "custom property value"}});
    client.trackException({exception: new Error("handled exceptions can be logged with this method"), tagOverrides:{"ai.operation.id": context.invocationId}});
    client.trackMetric({name: "custom metric", value: 3, tagOverrides:{"ai.operation.id": context.invocationId}});
    client.trackTrace({message: "trace message", tagOverrides:{"ai.operation.id": context.invocationId}});
    client.trackDependency({target:"http://dbname", name:"select customers proc", data:"SELECT * FROM Customers", duration:231, resultCode:0, success: true, dependencyTypeName: "ZSQL", tagOverrides:{"ai.operation.id": context.invocationId}});
    client.trackRequest({name:"GET /customers", url:"http://myserver/customers", duration:309, resultCode:200, success:true, tagOverrides:{"ai.operation.id": context.invocationId}});

    context.done();
};
```

Here is a very good article which explains  how application insight works and how we can configure the custom event tracking

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring