# Getting Exception message in application insights

Tags: azure-functions

I have a C# azure function that is throwing an exception:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            throw new Exception("Helpful message");
        }
```

The exception is catched by the runtime and re thrown. In application insight this is logged with the message `Exception while executing function: Function1` and the call stack. I am unable to find the "Helpful message" anywhere.

In Application Insights I see this and non of the Properties has the "Helpful message" text:
[image: Application Insights of the exception]

The callstack shows the location of the error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 321)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 117)
Inner exception System.Exception handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at FunctionApp1.Function1+<Run>d__0.MoveNext (FunctionApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullFunctionApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\sschoof\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\Function1.csFunctionApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 20)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeAsync>d__27.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 584)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 531)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__25.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 467)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 277)
```

My current workaround is:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Helpful message");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.LogError(e, e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Is there an better way to get the "Helpful message" than adding this to every function?

Comment: We just fixed a bug in UX (getting on its way to production) which results in similar behavior. To check whether this is the same issue - can you please paste a screenshot where you see only top message?

Comment: @ZakiMa: Thanks for the reply, I added a screenshot

Comment: yes, this is exactly the issue we fixed. Thank you for reporting it!

Comment: Should be fixed now. Please let us know if you still cannot see internal messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in UX. It was fixed on 3/28 and should be in prod around 4/2. Meanwhile you can access your messages in Analytics.

UX (before the fix):

[image]

Logs experience should still show messages:

[image]

After the fix (still on its way):

[image]

Comment: How to I got to the info in the screenshot "Analytics should still show messages:" ?

Comment: Found it in the top navigation of the overview

Comment: I have the same issue - where did you find it in the end @sschoof?

Comment: @Rodney, are you facing the same bug, i.e. message is not available? Can you please check that you clicked on Exception (and not positioned on Request or other telemetry item)?

Comment: To find it in raw view - go to Logs (Analytics got renamed to Logs) and explore Exceptions table.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#exceptions), to see detailed message, you'd better use the method `TrackException()` . Or use the method you mentioned in your question.

The following 2 examples using `TrackException()` in run.csx in azure portal:

**Example 1, not use try-catch block:**

```
#r "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"

using System;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();    

    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    log.LogInformation("a infor 567");    
    telemetry.TrackException(new Exception("Helpful message zzzzzz"));    

}
```

Check results in azure portal -> application insights:

[image]

**Example 2, use try-catch block:**

```
    #r "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"

    using System;
    using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

    public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();

        try
        {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        log.LogInformation("a infor 567");
        throw new Exception("Helpful message hahaha yyyyyy");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           telemetry.TrackException(ex);      
        }
    }
```

after execution, you can check the exceptions in azure portal -> application insights:

[image]

And if you're using visual studio to develop function app, you can just modify a little of the above code.

Comment: Azure Functions collect exceptions automatically. The problem is that it seems a message is lost. Sounds like a bug. For Azure Functions it is not recommended to track manually.

Comment: @ZakiMa, yes, I know it will auto collect telemetry. Maybe it's a bug, but not sure. And could you please let me know what's the impact if track manually?

Comment: It is most likely a bug. Also, if there is a task of logging exception - the right way is to do by using log.LogError (as author mentioned in a workaround). TrackException is for advanced scenarios (in context of Azure Functions) and not recommended. A link to a doc covers generic exception tracking in environments which don't track automatically.

Comment: @ZakiMa, but log.LogError would produce an redundant message, it requires another string message as parameter.

Comment: @ZakiMa, and could you please help confirm if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306784/javascript-azure-function-stacktrace-has-none-of-my-code-in-it) is the same issue? Many thanks.